# PDO in laravel is not going into the next loop after return

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

SO, I have a PDO statement that is working perfectly. It does what it should, and then it returns true (or false if I force bad data)

The issue is that it is not moving into the loop after the statement since it's returning true. How can I make it so that if the statement executes successfully without error, it moves into the foreach loop right after it?

```
$sql = "CALL TEST.PROCEDURE (
        :id    ,    
        :type ,   
        :name,      
    )";
    try {
        $pdo = DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo();
        $pdoStatement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':id',      $id,            \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':type',  $type,      \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':name',          $name,          \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $pdoStatement->execute();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
        return false;
    }
    return true;

    $newData = 0;

    foreach ($object->days as $key => $value) {
        dd($value); //this isn't dumping because the loop isn;t being hit
    }
```

Comment: Move the `return true;` after the loop

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, I'm not sure what I was thinking there.....